# Java - Creating dynamic YAML document programmatically

Tags: yaml

I'm on the search for a `yaml` document object model that will allow me to write the document **dynamically**.
I don't know the properties etc. in advance so I can't arrange a strong type object.
Here is a **pseudo** code of what I search for: (The syntax is not important, of course it can be different).

```java
Yaml yamlDoc = new Yaml();
YamlNode root = yamlDoc.addNode(null, "auto-update");

YamlNode forceUpdateNode = yamlDoc.addNode(root, "force-update");
forceUpdateNode.setValue("${AUTO_UPDATE_FORCE_UPDATE:false}");

YamlNode timeoutSeconds = yamlDoc.addNode(forceUpdateNode , "timeout-seconds");
timeoutSeconds.setValue("${AUTO_UPDATE_FORCE_UPDATE_TIMEOUT_SECONDS:10}");
```

The result `yaml` should look like:

```yaml
auto-update:
  force-update: ${AUTO_UPDATE_FORCE_UPDATE:false}
    timeout-seconds: ${AUTO_UPDATE_FORCE_UPDATE_TIMEOUT_SECONDS:10}
```

Both `SnakeYaml` and `Jackson` are aimed for serializing an object so they seem limited.
Another option is maybe to create some generic object and manually serialize it?

Answer (score 1):

SnakeYaml does provide an API for that:

```java
MappingNode root = new MappingNode(
        Tag.MAP, new ArrayList<NodeTuple>, DumperOptions.FlowStyle.BLOCK);
MappingNode autoUpdate = new MappingNode(
        Tag.MAP, new ArrayList<NodeTuple>, DumperOptions.FlowStyle.BLOCK);
root.getValue().add(new NodeTuple(
    new ScalarNode(
        Tag.STR, "auto-update", null, null, DumperOptions.ScalarStyle.PLAIN
    ), autoUpdate
));

NodeTuple forceUpdateEntry = new NodeTuple(
    new ScalarNode(
        Tag.STR, "force-update", null, null, DumperOptions.ScalarStyle.PLAIN
    ), new ScalarNode(
        Tag.STR, "${AUTO_UPDATE_FORCE_UPDATE:false}", null, null,
        DumperOptions.ScalarStyle.DOUBLE_QUOTED
    )
); 
autoUpdate.getValue().add(forceUpdateEntry);

NodeTuple timeoutSecondsEntry = new NodeTuple(
    new ScalarNode(
        Tag.STR, "timeout-seconds", null, null, DumperOptions.ScalarStyle.PLAIN
    ), new ScalarNode(
        Tag.STR, "${AUTO_UPDATE_FORCE_UPDATE_TIMEOUT_SECONDS:10}", null, null,
        DumperOptions.ScalarStyle.DOUBLE_QUOTED
    )
); 
autoUpdate.getValue().add(timeoutSecondsEntry);

Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
yaml.serialize(root, new PrintWriter(System.out));
```

As you can see, the API allows you to fine-tune output parameters (block vs flow mapping style, quoted vs plain scalar style, tags). You probably want to write some wrapper functions to make node creation simpler.